# runtime exception canot start activity

Tags: android

I have Written all the code well but i dont know what is the erroe and how to slove it.
While i run the programm the following error will occure

Login.java

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {


final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
private static final String TAG = "abc";
TextView create;

//Drawer
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

//End Drawer
private Button createacc;
private TextView trouble;
private EditText uname;
private EditText pass;

//Asynchronous task variable
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_login = "http://surun.co/demo/rest/login";


//Globalstring
String username =null;
String password = null;

//Global Variable for login  state checking
public static boolean loginflag = false;
//    RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Surun Support");

    // Start Drawer Settings
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navListlog);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_login);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F58634")));
    // End of Drawer Settings

    //Click Text Animation
    final Animation myanim, imganim;
    myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.link_text_anim);
    imganim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    //End of animation

    //Initialize the component
    final TextView txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Login);
     create=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.createacc);
    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edituser);
    uname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            validation.isValid(uname, ".+@.+\\.[a-z]+", "Invalid UserName", true);

        }
    });
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
    pass.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            validation.isValid(pass, "[0-9]{10}", "Invalid Mobile No", true);
        }
    });
    final ImageView ivlogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    trouble = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trouble_login);
    //end of initializing component

    //Creating underlined text
    String udata = "Create Account";
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(udata);
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, udata.length(), 0);
    create.setText(content);


    //end of creating underlined text
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.v("TEST", "TEST");
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Create Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registration_user.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });//End of On click for button

    //starting font settings this has prone to error try catch is mandatory while setting font(Overriding native font interface).
   try {
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/robotoregular.ttf");
        create.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception " + e);
    }
    //End of font settings
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //load preferences if exist
    String shareduser = sharedpreferences.getString("User", "");
    String sharedpass = sharedpreferences.getString("Password", "");
    if ((shareduser.length() > 0) || (sharedpass.length() > 0)) {
        //Navigating to main page
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserLogedIn.class);
        i.putExtra("user", shareduser);
        i.putExtra("pass", sharedpass);
        //Starting An Activity
        startActivity(i);
        //finish();
    } else {
     login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             if (uname.getText().length() <= 0 || pass.getText().length() <= 0) {
                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Fields Are Mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 toast.show();
                 trouble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 if (pass.getText().length() > 10) {
                     Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Four Characters Only...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     toast.show();
                     trouble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     //Log.v(TAG,"Not Valid");

                 }
             } else {
                 //Animate Button load animation from anim/rotate.xml
                 ivlogo.startAnimation(imganim);
                 username = uname.getText().toString();
                 password = pass.getText().toString();
                 //Sending Login Request To Server for validation Using Asynchronus Tasks where username and password as a parameter to method
                 Log.v(TAG, "Excuting check detail");
                 new CheckDetail().execute();
                 //Creating Shared Preferences


             }//end of else_if fields are valid


         }
     });//End of On click for button
    }//If no shared preferences found

}//End of onCreate function

/* public void startregistr(View v){
     Log.v("IN CREATE", "TEST");
      sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences( MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String name=sharedpreferences.getString("name","");
      String email=sharedpreferences.getString("email","");
      String mobile=sharedpreferences.getString("mobile","");
      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registration_user.class);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click on Create",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.v(TAG,"Error Occured");
  }*/
private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] menuitem = {"Home", "NewTicket", "MyTickets", "About Us", "Logout"};
    Integer[] imgid = {
            R.drawable.pc1,
            R.drawable.pc2,
            R.drawable.pc3,
            R.drawable.pc4,
            R.drawable.pc5,

    };
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, menuitem, imgid);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1) {

            }
        }
    });
}//End of Add Drawer Items

private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dashboard!");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Surun Infocore");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}//End of SetupDrawer

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}//End od OnPostCreate

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}//End of onConfigurationChanged

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_admin_home, menu);
    return true;
}//End of onCreateOptionMenu

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    //Remove Following Comment To Enable Drawer Toggling On Login Page

    /*// Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }*/

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}//End of onOptionItemSelected

/**
 * Background Async Task to Login by making HTTP Request
 */

class CheckDetail extends AsyncTask<String,String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "In Do in Background");
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", password));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json =jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_login, "POST", params);
            //Object Parsing Failed here hence by using trail guide using JSONParser.alternateJSONArray to parse user data.
            //Hence not using json instance of object using a BACKUP static variable of Parser class for proccessing.
            //To use this backup utility theme the process should be standard and return unique or two out put only or ether way use three logical step
            if(json != null) {
                // As if login fails it returns object handling fail logic here.
                //We can make it general by sending array from server side so we can only use alternateJSONArray variable
            }
            if(JSONParser.alternateJSONArray != null)
            {
               Log.v(TAG,"USING BACKUP ARRAY");
               //Check your log cat for JSON futher details
                for (int jsonArrayElementIndex=0; jsonArrayElementIndex < JSONParser.alternateJSONArray.length(); jsonArrayElementIndex++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectAtJsonArrayElementIndex = JSONParser.alternateJSONArray.getJSONObject(jsonArrayElementIndex);
                    if(jsonObjectAtJsonArrayElementIndex.getString("email").equals(username) && jsonObjectAtJsonArrayElementIndex.getString("mobile").equals(password))
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG,"Login Successful Now setting loginflag true");
                        loginflag = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //JSON is null ether no data or 204 returned by server
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, "Exception at end :" + e.toString());
            //Log.e("TAG", "Error......!RecoverIt");
        }

        return null ;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
         //super.onPostExecute();
       // pDialog.dismiss();

        if(loginflag==true)
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "Executing Shared Preferences...");
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("User", uname.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("Password", pass.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Succeed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            android.util.Log.v(TAG, "Login Succeed");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserLogedIn.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login failed,Invalid Details...!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            trouble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    String getMD5(String pass) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(pass.getBytes());
            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
            String hashtext = number.toString(16);
            // Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
            while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
            }
            return hashtext;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

/* private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result) {

        JSONObject resultObject = null;

        int returnedResult = 0;

        try {

            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);

            returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return returnedResult;

    }*/
}
```

Error Please Slove the problem I have changed the name or package name for personal reason So consider it as right and give me soiution

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.surun.suruninfocore/com.example.surun.suruninfocore.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.Login.onCreate(Login.java:161)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
```

XML File

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="#fff">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="#fff">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp" tools:context=".AdminHome">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/surun"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:maxHeight="130dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/edituser"
            android:hint="Username-Email_ID"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_surun"
            android:textColor="#ff000005"
            android:textColorHint="#71000000"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editpassword"
            android:hint="Password-Mobile_No"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_surun"
            android:textColor="#ff000005"
            android:textColorHint="#71000000"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:id="@+id/Login"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Create Account"
            android:id="@+id/createacc"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/button" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Trouble In Signing In"
            android:id="@+id/trouble_login"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ffff0000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navListlog"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: Its a NPE error. may be you are trying to set a null value to the create.setText()
Check if content is not null

Comment: Where to check is it content is null or not

Comment: the line create.setText(**content**). check whether **content** is null or not. Just put an if statement before your create.setText(**content**) and check if **content** is null, if yes make a toast that it is, else set the value to the textview

Comment: Post you layout XML file

Comment: what is the code line @ Login.java:161

Comment: @ Login.java:161   content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, udata.length(), 0);
       @ Login.java:162 create.setText(content);

Comment: I have Updated my question

Comment: make sure, android:id="@+id/createacc" is not defined for any other view in your xmls.

Comment: are you sure that `content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, data.length(), 0);` causes the exception? Beacuse I copied that part of your code to a new project and it's working for me.... :/

Comment: ya content.setSpan causes the exception

Answer (score 0):

I think you did mistake somewhere else in your xml file, please recheck it.

```
android:id="@id/btnClick"
```

it should be like this,

```
android:id="@+id/btnClick"
```

Please check in your xml file everywhere.

Comment: No there is no such id declared.All id are proper declared

Comment: Well, you need to check all your ids and its values, that's the concern with this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you are setting the text before binding the view in the class with the view in xml...

Put these two lines in onCreate() method after the setContentView(); statement...

```
trouble = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trouble_login);
```

create=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.createacc);

Let me know if this works for you.

And if it does, mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others...

Comment: <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Create Account"
                android:id="@+id/createacc"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/button" />

Comment: is this code present in "activity_login.xml"?

Comment: sorry i didn't see, it is there, let me check once again

Comment: ya also i added the xml code in question.check full xml file above

Comment: You haven't put the whole code of Login.java. I tested it and its running successfully, the error is at line no 161, put the whole code

Comment: I put all login code

Comment: @ Login.java:161 content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, udata.length(), 0); @ Login.java:162 create.setText(content);

Comment: Check my updated answer